# Modifing multiple DOM items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i am trying to change placeholders for values in a form if internet explorer is version 9 or 8, i got this pice of code.

```
if( $("html").data("version") == "IE9-10"  ){
        var brand = $(".brand input");
        var value = brand.attr("placeholder");
        var model = $(".model input");
        var value2 = model.attr("placeholder"); 
        brand.val(value);
        model.val(value2);
}
```

I will like to know if there is a way i can make code more simple and less repetitive to achieve this same effect, i just need to select .brand input and .model input, store it placeholder value and replace the in put value with the placeholder value, I will appreciate if you guys could help me with this.

here is the HTML, im using a plugin who convert select to custom design, but the plugin uses placeholder and I need to support ie9 and ie8, so ill show you the html of the select and the html output of the plugin.

```
<select name="brand" class="brand" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Marca</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Plugin Output

```
<div class="brand">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Marca">
    <ul>
        <li data-value="volvo" class="">Volvo</li>
        <li data-value="saab" class="">Saab</li>
        <li data-value="mercedes" class="">Mercedes</li>
        <li data-value="audi" class="">Audi</li>
        <li class="minict_empty">Ningun resultado concuerda con la palabra.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You only show the div.brand markup, but you said the .model case had failed. Can you please include ALL of your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.brand, .model').find('input').val(function(){
   return this.placeholder;
   // or $(this).attr('placeholder'); if IE cannot access the attribute directly
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/deE5A/

Comment: I didn't realize `.val()` accepted functions! I actually like this better than my answer. (Note for OP: You need jQuery 1.4+)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure it has been added since v1.4 (http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value). Most (*if not all*) ***setter*** functions support this syntax

Comment: This one worked really good for me @GabyakaG.Petrioli , but i still wana know why .each() doesn't worked, it was my primary option.

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez, you haven't posted the code that didn't work, so i cannot really comment on why it failed.. if you add it to your question i can take a look..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli hahahah sorry, this is the code 
$(".brand input, .model input").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
});

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing the same operation on each one, you could combine the selectors and use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
if( $("html").data("version") == "IE9-10"  ){
    $(".brand input, .model input").each(function () {
        // In this function, "this" is the raw DOM element being iterated over,
        // so $(this) is a jQuery wrapper around that element.

        var $this = $(this);   // I like caching to save jQuery constructor calls :-)
        $this.val($this.attr("placeholder"));
    });
}
```

Comment: i already used this one, butt seems not to work on ie9, it only replaces .brand input the other one remains white :( couldnt understand why

Comment: Can you please show us your HTML (edit your question)? Maybe there's something odd in the HTML that we're not taking into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".brand input, .model input").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
});
```

That should do it :).